# why doesn't scrollspy work?

Tags: javascript, scroll, navigation, scrollspy

My problem is that no class gets added to my navbar items on scrolling, so I can't get navbar styles to change, either. 
Here's my rendered html file:

body tag and navbar:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".contentsbar">
...
<div id="fs-navbar" class="contentsbar">
          <ol id="fs-nav-items">
            <li class="fs-nav-item">
              <a href="#introduction">
                Introduction
```

linked element:

```
<h1 id="introduction">Introduction</h1>
```

footer:

```
<script src='/js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/methods.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/localization.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/content.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/sticky.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/svgmap.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/zoom.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/scroll.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/globals.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/mt.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/hardware.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/main.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/carousel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

bootstrap.min.js loads.

Comment: any errors in your console? have you instantiated the plugin?

Comment: No errors. I think I haven't instantiated it, all i did was what you see. I'm a beginner in js and web dev, so I'd appreciate your help in this.

Comment: Looking at [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), looks like you shouldn't need to as you have used the data attributes on the body.  However, I don't see a scrollspy.js included in your js files

Comment: there is no scrollspy.js, bootstrap.js contains everything